# Bayes Theorem With Two Independent Tests

Tags: probability, statistics

The probability of having a certain disease is 3%. A test is created for this disease which has a 98% true positive rate and a 4% false positive rate. What is the probability of having the disease if you take the test twice and both results are positive, assuming the tests are independent?

I attempted this problem like this: Let D be the event of you actually having the disease, and P be the event that both tests have positive results. Then $P(D|P) = \frac{P(P|D)P(D)}{P(P)} =\frac{P(P|D)P(D)}{P(P|D)P(D) + P(P|D^c)P(D^c)}= \frac{(0.98)(0.98)(0.03)}{(0.98)(0.98)(0.03)+(0.04)(0.04)(0.97)} \approx 0.9488$. Is this the correct way to apply the conditions of independence and the multiple tests?

Answer (score 2):

Let's first look at a simpler case where the test is taken once and the result is positive.  We will adapt your notation; $D$ is the event you have the disease, $\bar D$ is the event you do not.  $P_1$ indicates one (out of one) positive test result; $\bar P_1$ is the event that the test is negative.

Then the desired probability is $\Pr[D \mid P_1]$, i.e. the conditional probability that you have the disease given a positive result from one test.  We are given $$\Pr[D] = 0.03, \\ \Pr[P_1 \mid D] = 0.98, \\ \Pr[P_1 \mid \bar D] = 0.04.$$

So by Bayes' theorem, $$\Pr[D \mid P_1] = \frac{\Pr[P_1 \mid D]\Pr[D]}{\Pr[P_1]}.$$  We already have the numerator terms, but the denominator, which represents the unconditional or marginal probability of a positive test result, needs further computation via the law of total probability:

$$\Pr[P_1] = \Pr[P_1 \mid D]\Pr[D] + \Pr[P_1 \mid \bar D]\Pr[\bar D],$$ where we have conditioned on whether or not you have the disease.  Now the rest is straightforward:

$$\Pr[D \mid P_1] = \frac{(0.98)(0.03)}{(0.98)(0.03) + (0.04)(1 - 0.03)} = 0.431085,$$

so a single positive test result means you have about a $43\%$ chance of actually having the disease.

Now, how do we generalize this to the case where two independent tests are taken?  The immediate idea is to let $P_2$ represent two (out of two) positive results, and as before,

$$\Pr[D \mid P_2] = \frac{\Pr[P_2 \mid D]\Pr[D]}{\Pr[P_2]}.$$  But here, we aren't directly given probabilities related to the event $P_2$.  We have to do additional calculations, which will rely on the assumption that the tests are independent.

Think of the outcome of each test as being like flipping a coin.  If you have the disease, you are flipping a coin whose probability of landing heads is $0.98$, and if it shows heads, that is a positive test result.  So if you flip the coin twice, the probability it shows heads twice will be $$\Pr[P_2 \mid D] = (0.98)^2 = 0.9604.$$  And if you don't have the disease, you're flipping a coin whose probability of landing heads is $0.04$.  So $$\Pr[P_2 \mid \bar D] = (0.04)^2 = 0.0016.$$  Now we have the required information to continue:

$$\Pr[D \mid P_2] = \frac{(0.9604)(0.03)}{(0.9604)(0.03) + (0.0016)(1 - 0.03)} = 0.948887.$$

So two independent positive test results means the probability of having the disease has increased to nearly $95\%$.

It is worth understanding what factors in Bayes' theorem influence the resulting probability in such a way.  Notice how even though the true "double positive" rate is slightly lower, $96.04\%$ versus $98\%$, this isn't what changes the probability.  What really explains the change is how the false "double positive" rate went from $4\%$ ($1$ in $25$ tests of someone without disease will incorrectly return positive) to $0.16\%$ ($1$ in $625$ tests of someone without disease will incorrectly return two positive results).  This is because the disease has low prevalence in the population:  $97\%$ of people are disease free.  So that reduction in false positive rate will have a huge impact on the posterior conditional probability of actually having the disease.

As an exercise, consider the following scenarios:

1. What if the disease is more common; e.g., $\Pr[D] = 0.40$?  Does a double positive test substantially change the probability over a single positive test in this case?
2. What if the disease is still uncommon as in the original problem, but the test is more unreliable, say $\Pr[P_1 \mid D] = 0.85$?  The false positive rate is still the same.  Does testing multiple times help increase diagnostic accuracy?
3. Now what if instead, $\Pr[P_1 \mid \bar D] = 0.15$, but $\Pr[P_1 \mid D] = 0.999$?  That is, the test is highly sensitive, but also has a high false positive rate?  How many times do you think such a test would need to be taken?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible scenarios:

1. You have the disease
2. You don't have the disease

If you have the disease, then there is a 98% chance that the test will correctly identify you (and a 2% chance it will give a false negative). Therefore *if you have the disease,* then the probability that you will get two positives is: $0.98^2 = 0.9604$. The probability of getting two false negatives would be $0.02^2 = 0.0004$ and the probability of getting one false negative and one true positive at $2*.02*0.98 = 0.0392$ (can verify that $1 - 0.0004 - 0.0392 = 0.9604$).

If you *do not* have the disease, then there is a 4% chance it will give a false positive twice: $0.04^2 = 0.0016$.

Now that we know the probabilities of getting two positives given the two possible scenarios, we simply add the probability of being in each of those scenarios to arrive at the probability that we get two positive test results:

$$
p = 0.03 * 0.9604 + 0.97 * 0.0016 = 0.030364
$$

Now, of those test results, we need to find "how many times does a person with the disease test positive twice": That's the probability of having the disease, $0.03$, times the probability of getting two positive test results (given you have the disease): $0.98^2 = 0.9604$. Which then gets us to the final result:

$$
p\left(\text{D} | \text{2+}\right) = \frac{p\left(\text{D}\right)*p
\left(\text{2+}|\text{D}\right)}{p\left(\text{2+}\right)} = \frac{0.03 * 0.98^2}{0.03 * 0.98^2 + 0.97 * 0.04^2} \approx 0.94889
$$